# Проблема вывода при использовании Iterator

Tags: java, json

При передаче ключей типа `Iterator`, возникает проблема вывода в методе `valueChecker()`. Я написал в комментариях к коду что не так с моим результатом. *Что я делаю не так ?*

```
public Map<Class, Object> JSONFormatStringSeparator(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
    while (keys.hasNext()){
       String key = keys.next();
       System.out.println(key); // выводит все ключи
    }
    String value = valueChecker(keys,jsonObject); // вызываю метод и передаю ключи и сам Json object
    System.out.println("After value checker!"); // выводит
    if(value!=null) {
        switch (value) {
            case "create-company":
                String [] array = {"id","compname","password","email"};
                if(keyChecker(keys,array) == array.length){
                    System.out.println("All found");
                    Company company = new Company(jsonObject.getLong("id"),jsonObject.getString("compname"),
                    jsonObject.getString("password"),jsonObject.getString("email"));
                    return objectMapper(Company.class,company);
                }
            }
        }

    return null;
}

private String valueChecker(Iterator<String> keys,JSONObject jsonObject){
    System.out.println("in the value checker!"); // выводит
    while(keys.hasNext()){ // не заходит и метод возврашает null!
        String key =  keys.next();
        System.out.println("in value checker loop!");
        if(key.equals("formId")){
          return (String)jsonObject.get(key);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы получаете итератор и *пролистываете* Вашу коллекцию до конца:

```
Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
while (keys.hasNext()){
    String key = keys.next();
    System.out.println(key);
}
```

Далее Вы передаете итератор в метод `valueChecker(...)`, а так в этот момент итератор находится на последней позиции, то `keys.hasNext()` возвращает `false`, а Ваш метод возвращает `null`.

Чтобы решить данную проблему, после вывода всех ключей (и перед вызовом метода `valueChecker(...)`)  запросите итератор повторно:

```
keys = jsonObject.keys();
```

А вообще, коль уж Вы передаете в метод сам `jsonObject`, то передавать итератор смысла нет. Просто получите в этом методе итератор от переданного объекта `jsonObject`.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что вы работаете с одним и тем же итератором и в самом же первом цикле доходите до его конца, поэтому последующие вызовы метода keys.hasNext() ничего не возвращают.
Поскольку сбросить итератор в начало в java нельзя, вам нужно каждый раз вызывать *jsonObject.keys()*:

```
String value = valueChecker(jsonObject.keys(), jsonObject);
```

Только в таком случае совершенно незачем передавать и ключи и объект - проще передать json-объект, а ключи получить внутри метода:

```
private String valueChecker(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
    ...
}
```

Но весь ваш метод *valueChecker* какой-то неправильный - ни итератор, ни цикл там не нужны. Гораздо проще записать так (и заодно дать методу осмысленное название):

```
private String getFormAction(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    if (jsonObject.has("formId")) {
        return jsonObject.getString("formId");
    }

    return null;
}
```